# Getting records of today according to time zone

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with column reg_data indicating the timestamp (date and hour) of the record. I want to get the transaction of today according to timezone Asia/Singapore. I used date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore"), but it did not work. So I use the code below. Still it does not work. Please advice.

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  from transaksi 
 WHERE date('Y-m-d', strtotime('reg_date')) = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')-(60*60*16))
";
```

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` sets the timezone for PHP, not your database.

Comment: I'd suggest to provide the SQL schema (in particular for your 'reg_date' column; cf. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) so we can help you to sort things out and to hopefully solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing PHP functions inside your SQL statement. PHP does not have access to 'reg_date' field unless you query it from the database first.

Assuming 'reg_date' is a DATETIME field, try this:

```
$curtime_asia = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Now')-(60*60*16));
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  from transaksi 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(reg_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = ".$curtime_asia;
```

If 'reg_date' is not a DATETIME field, the DATE_FORMAT function may not work though.

Comment: The format of reg_date is in the form of 2020-02-01 23:12:23

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to convert the stored datetime in MySQL to a different timezone value.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'America/New_York');
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'America/New_York') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-01-31 21:15:16                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can use the result and compare it with another `DATETIME` value:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'America/New_York') < '2020-02-01 00:00:00';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'America/New_York') < '2020-02-01 00:00:00' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam') < '2020-02-01 00:00:00';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2020-02-01 02:15:16', 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam') < '2020-02-01 00:00:00' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Build your `WHERE` conditition around the `CONVERT_TZ` function, something like this:

```
SELECT
    columns... 
FROM
    transaksi
WHERE
    CONVERT_TZ(reg_date, 'UTC', 'your_target') BETWEEN
            DATE(NOW())
        AND
            DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```